# Setting delays on each iteration of a loop with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, loops, delay

I'm trying to create a very simple countdown.
When someone hits 'Pick random winner' it executes selectWinner().

I've been trying to figure out how to execute the loop with a slight delay between 3,2,1. For some reason no matter where I put the setTimeout or setInterval it keeps executing it AFTER the entire loop.

Any tips?

```
// Picking name from sorting hat
const randomNumber = function () {
    winningNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * winners.length) + 1;
}

function selectWinner() {
    for (let i = 3; i < 4; i--) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            setInterval(() => console.log(i), 500);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your approach:

- `for` or any other looping mechanism are synchronised and will not wait.
- `setInterval` will run the function at every tick. So if you add it in every iterations, you will add multiple intervals.
- Whenever using `setInterval` accept the timer reference so that you may close it in future, if required

---

You can try this approach:

- Use recursion to create loop instead.
- Since you have control on when to call the function, you can add delay here

**Example using `setTimeout`**

```js
let count = 3

function showCoundown() {
  if (count) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(count--);
      showCoundown();
    }, 1000)
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Winner is ...')
    }, 1000)
  }
}
showCoundown();
```

**Example using `setInterval`**

```js
let count = 3
function showCoundown(count) {
  if (count === 0) {
    console.log('Winner is ...');
  } else {
    console.log(count)
  }
}

function createInterval() {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    showCoundown(count--);
    if (count < 0) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
    }
  }, 1000)
}
createInterval();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is the every time you call setTimeout/setInterval, it queues up something to happen after a delay. But your main code keeps on running.

e.g.

```
console.log(1)
setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 100)
console.log(3)
```

This will output 1 then 3, and after a delay, 2 will be outputed. Javascript doesn't stop everything to wait for the setTimeout to happen, it keeps doing other tasks.

There's a couple ways you can achieve what you're trying to do. The most basic option (which I would recommend for you) would be to just not have a for loop - make your setInterval act like your for loop instead (meaning, let the interval do the looping for you). Here's a working example:

```js
function countdown() {
  let i = 4
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    i--;
    console.log(i)
    if (i === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 500)
}

countdown()
```

What's going on here is the interval function will get called repeatedly (every 500 ms). Every time it gets called, it'll decrement i and log it. Once i reaches 0, clearInterval is called to stop the repetition.

For those familiar with async/await, you can just await a timeout, so that you can keep the for loop.

```js
const sleep = timeout => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout))

async function countdown() {
  for (let i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(i)
    await sleep(500)
  }
}

countdown()
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
function selectWinner() {
  for (let i = 3, x = 1; i >= 0; i--, x++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i !== 0) {
        console.log(i);
      } else {
         console.log('and the winner is...');
      }
    }, 500 * x)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Sory. I did'nt noticed it's setInterval. I fixed it.

Comment: It still will not work properly. Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can make a snippet using it. Also, *Is this what you want?* is not an explanation. Kindly explain what and why you changed

Comment: Also, no need to apologise to anyone. We all make mistakes